# Кодировка сайте SMARTY

Tags: кодировка, smarty

Есть сайт на польском языке самописный на SMARTY.
Был перенесен с одного хостинга на другой. Сейчас сайт показывает в местах где должна быть польская буква - знаки вопроса. Уже второй день сижу над данной проблемой

Забыл уточнить

Проблема из даными которые беруться из базы даных

На первом хостинге

**character_set_server = latin1** 
на новом 
**character_set_server = latin2**

Пробовал дописывать у файл перед подключениям **"require_once 'libs/Smarty.class.php';"** так как пишет в документации

```
if (function_exists('mb_internal_encoding')) {
  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
}
define('SMARTY_RESOURCE_CHAR_SET', 'UTF-8');
require_once 'libs/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

но результата от того не было.
Из смарти не работал.

Буду благдарен за помощь.

Comment: А проблема с просто html контентом или данными из базы?

Comment: Так сайт у вас возможно не в UTF-8.

Comment: А вы настраивали кодировку данных из базы? `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");`

Comment: Visman, у всех .tpl стоит charset=utf-8

Comment: Telion, нет не настраивал, я из сматри не работал - незнаю как это зделать, где прописать даный код - там где идет подключении к базе ?

Comment: @klifort при чем тут смарти, подключение к БД там вроде происходит точно так же. Файл подключения к бд поправьте и в конец добавьте кдировку выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне хватает этих двух строчек что бы работал мультиязычный сайт:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
$database = ''; // имя базы данных
$user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
$password = ''; // пароль

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));

mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло,

Answer (score 0):

Это вообще никак не связано со Smarty (это шаблонизатор, который только отделяет html от кода). Если ситуация возникает только с данными из БД, то для начала попробуйте перевести свою базу в кодировку UTF-8. Далее при подключении укажите кодировку :

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'test');
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

Также не забудьте указать эту кодировку в заголовке страницы.

P.S. Старайтесь не использовать кодировки ACSII (latin1, windows-1251). На современных проектах это не самые удобные вещи (особенно, если используете AJAX, WebSockets).

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8;` - это неправильный подход! Читайте замечания http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php А у PDO кодировка указывается в $dsn.

Comment: @Visman поправил ответ